# Failed to load large JavaScript file ExpressJS after uglifying

Tags: javascript, node.js, minify, uglifyjs

All my scripts are compressed and minified used uglifyJS:

[image: minify all files]

The size of this file "app.min.js" is 982.1KB however when I tried to run the node server and open the app in the browser It's stopped in 502kB

[image: running the server]

and after some while

[image]

I don't know what happened there, Is there any limitation on Javascript file '502kB' ?
what I miss

Comment: How you opened the page? Using some http server or just from file://path/to/index.html ?

Comment: remote server not from local machine

Comment: could you please try to download the necessary js file via wget from that remove server?

Comment: I guess that the cause of trouble is in http server or your connection to remote server. I highly recommended to use nginx for serving static files. nodejs is best but nginx is better(for serving static).

Comment: I can do that or I can split files to pieces but I need to know why that happened?

Comment: Firstly you should find the cause of the trouble. The nginx will check our version about expressjs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [this](https://blog.benhall.me.uk/2011/12/using-nginx-to-server-static-files-instead-of-node-js/) article may help you, it is all about `nodejs` server serving static content, so nginx is recommended to do this purpose.

If you have to use `nodejs` server then you should make all files smaller in terms of size, no need for example to minimize libraries files as `jquery` since it is already minimized, scripts should be minimized only, you can even minimize all libs files into one javascript file called `libs.min.js` as example and the rest of your scripts in another file called `script.min.js`.